# Should we have tags corresponding to common nutrients of concern?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are [several](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/a/41/1236) nutrients that vegetarians and vegans may want to pay extra attention to. Currently we have tags for some of them, but not all of them.

#### Tags we have

- [b12](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/b12) x14
- [protein](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/protein) x18

#### Tags we don't have

- [iron](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/iron) eg. [How to obtain the best iron absorption from spinach?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/375/how-to-obtain-the-best-iron-absorption-from-spinach)
- [vitamin-a](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vitamin-a) eg. [Is Vitamin A plentiful in cooked or raw vegetables?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/290/is-vitamin-a-plentiful-in-cooked-or-raw-vegetables/434#434)
- [vitamin-d](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vitamin-d) eg. [Are (plant-based) vitamin D₂ supplements as effective as vitamin D₃?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/q/371/1236)
- [omega-3](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/omega-3) eg. [Is Omega 3 missing from vegan diets?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/136/is-omega-3-missing-from-vegan-diets)
- [calcium](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/calcium) eg. [Do vegan diets contain enough calcium?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1/do-vegan-diets-contain-enough-calcium)
- [zinc](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/zinc) eg. [How can vegans obtain sufficient zinc from whole foods?](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/1333/how-can-vegans-obtain-sufficient-zinc-from-whole-foods)

I can imagine that somebody might visit this site looking for information about specific nutrients either after receiving a deficiency diagnosis or just from hearing about it somewhere else. Do we want to create tags for specific nutrients, or just keep things as they are and rely on the broader [vitamins-and-minerals](https://vegetarianism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/vitamins-and-minerals) in combination with keyword searching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it would be good to have tags for specific nutrients. I agree that people are likely to use those terms when searching and the ability to search by tag would eventually be very helpful, when the site has many more questions...